# Google Mailhide onclick event doesn't open link in popup window

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to use Google Mailhide to hide my email address from spam bots.

[[**Check the same code on Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/8Qi8N8QF)]

```
<p>Contact me: robin<a href="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01v7EWmtV61H3m2_TY5wG32Q==&amp;c=QRu73666IUcwkC6_Q0AyxXUJ-sEg46KlJ66HFM8LhmHlcQ=" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k\07501v7EWmt6V61H3m2_TY5wG632Q\75\75\46c\75QRu736IU6cwkC6_Q0AyxXUJ-sEg4KlJ666HFM8LhmHlcQ\075', '', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=300'); return false;" title="Reveal this e-mail address">...</a>@gmail.com</p>
```

As you can see, the onclick event is being used to execute some JavaScript code -- essential for opening the link in a popup window. But it doesn't seem to be working as I am simply being taken to the link itself.

Is something wrong with the JavaScript code?

(PS: I am on Kubuntu Linux and using Chrome.)

Comment: It [open in new window](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/Armz6/) on my machine.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa a new 500x300px popup window or a new tab/window?

Comment: 500x300, but it may be prevented on the client side.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I don't understand. The JSFiddle example, opens fine in a 500x300px popup window for me too. But not on my website. Weird.

Comment: Do you have a live link to your website?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Sure! This one: http://bit.ly/HhvGoQ

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa And I just realized that the JS part is being stripped somehow. It's probably my theme itself. Since this is subjective, this question should be closed, right?

Comment: Ah. You found it out yourself :) Either close the question (or accept an answer either mine or add an answer yourself if it is going to be better) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>geek<a href="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01v7EWmtV61H3m2_TY5wG32Q==&amp;c=QRu736IUcwkC6_Q0AyxXUJ-sEg4KlJ66HFM8LhmHlcQ=" title="Reveal this e-mail address">...</a>@gmail.com</p>
```

The javascript part isn't in there. Something is wrong.